# Meaning of 'to' in the dictionaries

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

The word 'set' is defined in certain dictionaries as:

[[OED]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set?q=set) put, lay, or stand (something) in a specified place or position
[[Random House]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set?s=t) **to** put (something or someone) in a particular place

The latter dictionary’s explanation for ‘set’ starts with ‘to.’ Does this imply ‘this word means to-‘?

Comment: You are linking to the [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/about) (Oxford Dictionaries Online), not the [OED](http://public.oed.com/about/) (Oxford English Dictionary).  The latter has a much longer definition with many more senses, though the ODO's focus on modern English may be more immediately useful to you as a language learner.

Comment: @snailplane, Thank you for your introduction of new information about Oxfords. I always learn more than is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To* in this case is not the preposition but the *infinitive marker*.

It is attached to the infinitive form (the *bare infinitive*) in 'abstract' contexts like this and in a variety of actual syntactical constructions to make clear that it is the infinitive which is intended. This is necessary because the infinitive of almost every English verb has exactly the same form as the *present tense* form.

(The exceptions are *be*, whose *present tense* form is *are*, and the full modals *can*, *may*, *must*, *shall*, *will*, which have no infinitive form.)

This convention is so strong that the *marked infinitive*, with *to*, is often said in sub-academic texts to be "**the** infinitive form"; but this is not quite accurate: it is "**an** infinitive form".

ADDENDUM:
Since writing this I have been informed by Prof. Lawler at ELU that the preferred term among  Very Advanced Students is not *infinitive marker* but *complementizer*. I was beginning to lean toward *nominalizer*, but Prof. Lawler does not approve that.

Comment: We no longer think of *ought* as the past of *owe*, either.

Comment: @tchrist *Ought*, though, is nonetheless classified as a semi-modal because unlike the others it takes a marked infinitive to complete the construction.

Comment: And even that only in positive declarative sentences like “He ought to leave”, not in negatives or interrogatives: “You really ought not do that”; “Ought we decamp forthwith?” And yes, I meant to use the silly old world there, because it has that musty odor about it.

Comment: @tchrist My impression is that that is a relatively late development, as folks tried to adapt it more towards a 'regular' modal. For instance, a quick glance at a Shakespeare concordance shows only one use with unmarked infinitive against 18 with marked infinitive. And (to the extent we're not just replacing *ought* with *should*) we're now backing away from the unmarked complement. I think in 100 years we'll be seeing the John Lawlers of the world saying it's an adverb, as in "You shouldn't oughta do that."

Answer (score 2):

"**to** *put*" is the [*infinitive form*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm) and is often used in dictionary definitions of verbs.